# Add pandas dummy into numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which represents forest fires. This dataset has numerical features and categorical features. These categorical ones are date and month. I changed these categorical values into numericals for example:

```
Jan -> 1
Feb -> 2
March ->3
.
.
Dec -> 12
```

and

```
Mon -> 1
Tue -> 2
.
.
Sun ->7
```

But using this method isn't correct. I should have used dummies to make it correct.

A little part of my dataset is:

```
7   5   mar fri 86.2    26.2    94.3    5.1 8.2 51  6.7 0
7   4   oct tue 90.6    35.4    669.1   6.7 18  33  0.9 0
7   4   oct sat 90.6    43.7    686.9   6.7 14.6    33  1.3 0
```

And I guess I had to change it to

```
7   5   [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0] 86.2    26.2    94.3    5.1 8.2 51  6.7 0
7   4   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]   [0,1,0,0,0,0,0] 90.6    35.4    669.1   6.7 18  33  0.9 0
7   4   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]   [0,0,0,0,0,1,0] 90.6    43.7    686.9   6.7 14.6    33  1.3 0
```

Now what I did:

```
data[:, 2] = pandas.get_dummies(data[:,2])
data[:, 3] = pandas.get_dummies(data[:,3])
```

This method doesn't obivously. I knew it when I wrote it.

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (517,12) into shape (517)
```

How can I merge the dummies into my `numpy` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier than what you have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df)

df
Out[33]: 
   a  b    m    d     e     f      g    h     i   j    k  l
0  7  5  mar  fri  86.2  26.2   94.3  5.1   8.2  51  6.7  0
1  7  4  oct  tue  90.6  35.4  669.1  6.7  18.0  33  0.9  0
2  7  4  oct  sat  90.6  43.7  686.9  6.7  14.6  33  1.3  0


df1
Out[35]: 
   a  b     e     f      g    h     i   j    k  l  m_mar  m_oct  d_fri  d_sat  \
0  7  5  86.2  26.2   94.3  5.1   8.2  51  6.7  0      1      0      1      0   
1  7  4  90.6  35.4  669.1  6.7  18.0  33  0.9  0      0      1      0      0   
2  7  4  90.6  43.7  686.9  6.7  14.6  33  1.3  0      0      1      0      1   

   d_tue  
0      0  
1      1  
2      0
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please bear in mind that there is a drop_first parameter in pd.get_dummies. It is used very often with classification and regression models in order to ensure you don't have linearly dependent features in the model. So, you would have to decide whether you need to include it (e.g. drop_first=True) or not. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html